# Load a file from the 'views' directory

Tags: grails

I want to load an existing file from views folder (not a gsp). For example:

```
grails-app/views/test.txt
```

How can I load it as a File and serve it as a content to the browser?

Thanks

Comment: Load it where? As a `File` in your app, serve it as content to a browser? Stream it as binary data to some UDP server? You need more detail to your question. Plus showing what you have already tried will help too.

Comment: put it under `/web-app` thus you can serve it's content via browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groovyPageResourceLoader` to resolve this resource. Here is a very simple example:

```
package example

class MyController {

    def groovyPageResourceLoader

    def index() {
        def resource = groovyPageResourceLoader.getResource("/grails-app/views/testing.txt")
        // if you want the browser to handle the file (download)
        render(file: resource.getFile(), contentType: "plain/text", fileName: resource.getFilename())
       // or you could read the contents of the resource.getFile() and do whatever you want.
    }
}
```